# How to select specific column for column that has value "1" [MYSQL]

Tags: mysql, sql

Does anyone know of a query to get the following results in mysql

| Name | Item A | Item B | Item C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jhon | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Lee | 1 | 0 | 0 |

and i want to choose name Jhon, that have value 1 on column "Item B" and "Item C" so the result will be:

| Name | Item B | Item C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jhon | 1 | 1 |

or select 'Lee' will be:

| Name | Item A |
| --- | --- |
| Lee | 1 |

I want to know the query code of mysql of that problem, thank you

Comment: Queries dont' work that way.  You must define what columns to return.  One could use dynamic SQL however in two steps  1st get all columns which have a 1; then generate a dynamic SQL statement for adding in desired colums having 1.

Comment: Unless you want to return a single column that can contains multiple values, combined as array, string or json.

Comment: I would restructure the source table as name - item type - value where the item type column would indicate if the row is for A, B, or C item type. Why? Because sql databases are optimised to search column by column, not row by row. You can then pivot the resultset around either in sql (not really recommended) or in a reporting application to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

What Shadow said:

```sql
with cte_jx as (
select name, 'itemA' as item_key, itemA as item_value from t_jx
union all
select name, 'itemB' as item_key, itemB as item_value from t_jx
union all
select name, 'itemC' as item_key, itemC as item_value from t_jx)
select *
  from cte_jx
 where name ='Jhon'
   and item_value <> 0;
```

Result:

```
name|item_key|item_value|
----+--------+----------+
Jhon|itemB   |         1|
Jhon|itemC   |         1|
```

Pivot the row back to column as needed.